# Localization issue when mod converts answer to the part of question

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, localization, russian-stackoverflow

[Here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/714910/3) is edit when mod converts answer to the part of the question. And such text:

> appended answer 714941 as supplemental

should be make allowed to translate. Also, using raw number `714941` here looks not very well. Maybe it could be better if it was a clickable link or completely removed.

Comment: The answer is deleted when this action is performed, so linking to it wouldn't really be any friendlier. Agree this should be localized though.

Comment: @Shog9 10k+ rep users can see it. For low rep users even the number here is not informative.

Comment: 10k rep users can see it without even clicking through to the revision history; it'll be right there on the question page.

Comment: @Shog9 except when answer is from another question (if it possible), If not then much better to remove id here at all.

Comment: That's not possible without... Lots of other stuff happening. Let's dismiss that possibility. The ID is included for the slightly more plausible scenario wherein someone leaves multiple updates to their own question in the form of multiple answers and they *all* have to be converted to edits - this allows someone to sort out the history if need-be, but shouldn't normally be required to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This string is in translation engine now. Translated on [ruSO](https://ru.traducir.win/string/9549) and will be live on the next update/rebuild.